SharePoint 2019 SPFx application customizer is not installed properly on my root site while it is working good in other site collection
can someone please help in getting this resolved SharePoint 2019 SPFx application customizer is not installed properly on my root site while it is working good in other site collection
what are possible reasons?

Please check if the deployment scope of the application customizer is set correctly. If it was deployed at the site collection level, it may not be available on the root site if it was not activated there.
